# why is font-awesome icon displaying the icon too small and off center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
;
(function($) {
  class Popup {

    constructor(options, elem) {
      var self = this;

      var defaultPopupMenu = `<div>
                                        <a href="#"><i id="faInfo" class="fa fa-info"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#"><i id="faQuest" class="fa fa-question"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" title="Link to example.com"><i id="faLink" class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                                    </div>`;

      this.defaultOptions = {
        content: defaultPopupMenu, //this option MUST be set when new options passed through, or only the default menu will show
        position: "top", //where the popup will show by default- top. Other options: right, bottom, or left
        theme: "popupTheme", //Menu Element theme. Defaults to popupTheme, but custom class can be set instead
        style: "", //Popup Menu Style. Default no style, will revert to default colours. Other options: Blue, Red, Green, Custom
        animation: "standard", //Standard animation by default. Other options: flip, grow, bounce
        event: "click", //Default set to "click", can also be set to hover
        hideOnClick: true, //When true, clicking off the menu closes it. When false, only clicking on the menu closes it
        zIndex: 100, //Individual z-index can be set for each menu for layering if necessary

        //function to handle actions when clicking on popup menu icons. MUST be set when options are passed through or an error or default menu actions will occur 
        popItemClick: function(globalthis) {
          //Default actions
          var twentyEightSpaces = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;

          var twentyFourSpaces = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;

          var eightSpaces = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;

          var sixteenSpaces = `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`;

          var content;
          var container = $(event.target).attr("id");

          switch (container) {
            case "faInfo":
              content = {
                type: "info",
                heading: "Information",
                text: `<p>To set a new menu when calling .popup() on an element,  
                                            you must set a variable that holds a string with the html for that menu, then 
                                            pass that variable through as the "content" part of the options. For example: </p>
                                            <p>var myMenu = '&lt;div&gt;&#92; <br />
                                            ${twentyEightSpaces}&lt;a href="#''&gt;&lt;i id="faInfo" class="fa fa-info"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&#92;<br />
                                            ${twentyFourSpaces}&lt;/div&gt;'; </p>
                                            <p>would create a menu with one item, and just add more '&lt;a&gt;' tags with icons inside the '&lt;div&gt;' tags to add more menu items. </p> 
                                            <p>Then add it to the content when calling the popup: </p>
                                            <p>$("#myPopUp").popup({ <br />
                                            ${eightSpaces}content: myMenu, <br />
                                            ${eightSpaces}popItemClick(globalthis) { <br />
                                            ${sixteenSpaces}...new actions here... <br />
                                            ${eightSpaces}} <br />
                                            });</p>
                                            <p>You must set new actions in the "popItemClick" function for your menu 
                                            in the options you pass or it will throw an error.</p>`
              }
              globalthis.alertBox(content);
              break;
            case "faQuest":
              content = {
                type: "info",
                heading: "Question",
                text: `<p>Why is this being shown?</p>
                                           <p>Because you need to set a popup menu of your own (and the popItemClick() function) or you get this default menu.</p>
                                           <p>If you set the popup menu but don't change the popItemClick() function, you will get an error.</p>
                                           <p>Click the "i" button for more info.</p>`
              }
              globalthis.alertBox(content);
              break;
            case "faLink":
              window.open("http://example.com/");
              break;
            default:
              content = {
                type: "danger",
                heading: "Error",
                text: `<p>Error! You have set a new menu without changing the 'popItemClick' function. 
                                           The 'popItemClick' function must be set to new menu actions.</p>`
              }
              globalthis.alertBox(content);
          }
        }
      }

      this.elem = elem;
      this.$elem = $(elem);
      this.options = $.extend({}, this.defaultOptions, options);

      if (!this.$elem.hasClass(this.options.theme)) {
        this.$elem.addClass(this.options.theme);
      }

      this.init();
    }

    init() {

      this.popup = $('<div class="pop-cont" />')
        .addClass('pop-' + this.options.position)
        .addClass('popupTheme' + this.options.style)
        .append('<div class="pop-items" />')
        .appendTo('body').css("opacity", 0).hide();

      this.setContent();
      this.setTriggers();
    }

    setContent() {
      var self = this;
      var location = this.popup.find(".pop-items");
      var content;

      if ((this.options.position == 'top') || (this.options.position == 'bottom')) {

        content = $(this.options.content).find("a").addClass("pop-item");
        location.html(content);
        this.popup.find("i").first().addClass("leftBorder");
        this.popup.find("i").last().addClass("rightBorder");

      } else if ((this.options.position == 'left') || (this.options.position == 'right')) {

        content = $(this.options.content).find("a").addClass("pop-item").addClass('item-side');
        location.html(content);
        this.popup.find("i").first().addClass("topBorder");
        this.popup.find("i").last().addClass("bottomBorder");

      }

      //popItemClick callback****************************************
      location.find('.pop-item').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        self.options.popItemClick.call(this, self);
      });
    }

    setTriggers() {
      var self = this;

      if (this.options.event === 'click') {
        this.$elem.on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (self.$elem.hasClass('pressed')) {
            self.pophide();
          } else {
            self.popshow();
          }
        });
      }

      if (this.options.event === 'hover') {
        this.$elem.on('mouseenter', function(event) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            self.popshow();
            self.popup = $(self.popup[0]);
          }, 250);
        });

        $(this.popup).on('mouseleave', function(event) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            self.pophide();
          }, 1000);
        });
      }

      if (this.options.hideOnClick === true) {
        $('html').on('click.popup', function(event) {
          if (event.target != self.elem && self.$elem.has(event.target).length === 0 &&
            self.popup.has(event.target).length === 0 && self.popup.is(":visible")) {
            self.pophide();
          }
        });
      }
    }

    pophide() {
      var self = this;
      var animation = {
        opacity: 0
      };
      this.$elem.removeClass('pressed');

      switch (this.options.position) {
        case 'top':
          animation.top = '+=20';
          break;
        case 'left':
          animation.left = '+=20';
          break;
        case 'right':
          animation.left = '-=20';
          break;
        case 'bottom':
          animation.top = '-=20';
          break;
      }
      this.popup.animate(animation, 200, function() {
        self.popup.hide();
      });
    }

    popshow() {
      this.$elem.addClass('pressed');
      this.setPosition();
      this.popup.show().css({
        opacity: 1
      }).addClass('animate-' + this.options.animation);
    }

    setPosition() {
      var self = this;
      this.coords = this.$elem.offset();
      var x = this.coords.left;
      var y = this.coords.top;
      var popWidth = this.popup.width();
      var popHeight = this.popup.height();
      var adjLeft = popWidth / 2;
      var adjTop = popHeight / 2;

      this.testy = $('<div class="test" />')
        .css({
          display: 'inline-block',
          margin: '0px',
          padding: '0px'
        })
        .appendTo('body');

      var measure = this.$elem.clone().css({
        padding: "0px",
        margin: "0px"
      });
      var loc = this.testy;
      loc.html(measure);

      var textWidth = this.testy.width();
      var textHeight = this.testy.height();
      this.testy.remove();

      var adjMenuWidth = textWidth / 2;
      var adjMenuHeight = textHeight / 2;
      var up = y - (popHeight + 7);
      var down = y + textHeight;

      if (this.popup.hasClass('pop-top')) {
        this.popup.css({
          top: up + "px",
          left: (x - adjLeft + adjMenuWidth + 5) + "px",
          right: "auto",
          'z-index': this.options.zIndex
        });
      }

      if (this.popup.hasClass('pop-bottom')) {
        this.popup.css({
          top: (down + 7) + "px",
          left: (x - adjLeft + adjMenuWidth + 5) + "px",
          right: "auto",
          'z-index': this.options.zIndex
        });
      }

      if (this.popup.hasClass('pop-left')) {
        this.popup.css({
          top: (y - adjTop + adjMenuHeight + 5) + "px",
          left: (x - popWidth - 2) + "px",
          right: "auto",
          'z-index': this.options.zIndex
        });
      }

      if (this.popup.hasClass('pop-right')) {
        this.popup.css({
          top: (y - adjTop + adjMenuHeight + 5) + "px",
          left: (x + textWidth + 12) + "px",
          right: "auto",
          'z-index': this.options.zIndex
        });
      }
    }

    alertBox(content) {
      var self = this;
      var myAlert = `<div id="alertBox" class="alert">
                                <div class="alert-content">
                                    <div class="alert-header">
                                        <h2></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="alert-body"></div>
                                    <div class="alert-footer">
                                        <button class="alert-close">OK</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;

      $('body').append(myAlert);

      this.alert = $('#alertBox');
      this.header = this.alert.find('div.alert-header');
      this.heading = this.header.find('h2');
      this.alertBody = this.alert.find('div.alert-body');
      this.footer = this.alert.find('div.alert-footer');
      this.close = this.footer.find('button.alert-close');


      this.heading.append(content.heading);
      this.alertBody.append(content.text);

      switch (content.type) {
        case "info":
          this.header.addClass("info");
          this.footer.addClass("info");
          this.close.addClass("info");
          break;
        case "success":
          this.header.addClass("success");
          this.footer.addClass("success");
          this.close.addClass("success");
          break;
        case "danger":
          this.header.addClass("danger");
          this.footer.addClass("danger");
          this.close.addClass("danger");
          break;
        case "warning":
          this.header.addClass("warning");
          this.footer.addClass("warning");
          this.close.addClass("warning");
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      this.alert.show();

      var closeBtn = $("button.alert-close");

      closeBtn.on("click", function() {
        self.alert.remove();
      });

      $(document).on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.target == self.alert[0]) {
          self.alert.remove();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  //Set $.fn.popup so it returns an instance of the Popup class when called*******************************
  $.fn.popup = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var popobject = new Popup(options, this);
    });
  };

}(jQuery));

/*jshint multistr: true */

//this is a sample .js file that shows how you might set up the popup menus

;
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#defaultTest').popup();

  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
/*Default theme**************/

.popupTheme {
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popupTheme i,
.popupThemeRed i,
.popupThemeBlue i,
.popupThemeGreen i,
.popupThemeCustom i {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popupTheme i:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.pop-cont.pop-top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop-cont.pop-bottom::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -14px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333 transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop-cont.pop-left::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #333;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop-cont.pop-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -14px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  border-width: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #333 transparent transparent;
  z-index: 100;
}

.pop-cont {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888;
}

.pop-cont,
.pop-item,
.popupTheme {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}


/*Individual menu item*/

.pop-item {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}

.item-side {
  float: none !important;
}

.pop-item i {
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.pop-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.pop-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.pop-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.pop-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.animate-standard {
  animation: animateStandard 0.3s 1 ease;
  -webkit-animation: animateStandard 0.3s 1 ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateStandard {
  from {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animateStandard {
  from {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animate-grow {
  animation: animateGrow 0.4s 1 ease;
  -webkit-animation: animateGrow 0.4s 1 ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateGrow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.5) translate(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animateGrow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.5) translate(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animate-flip {
  animation: animateFlip 0.4s 1 ease;
  -webkit-animation: animateFlip 0.4s 1 ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animateFlip {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(2, 2, 2, 180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes animateFlip {
  from {
    transform: rotate3d(2, 2, 2, 180deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.leftBorder {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}

.rightBorder {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.bottomBorder {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.topBorder {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}


/* The Alert Box (background) */

.alert {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1001;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 250px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.alert-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  max-width: 700px;
  min-width: 300px;
  /*width settings for different browsers. Note that these won't work at all for IE and versions of Edge before v79*/
  width: fit-content;
  /*works in chrome and opera*/
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  /*works for firefox */
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  /*works for Edge v79 and up*/
  width: -ms-fit-content;
  width: -o-fit-content;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.alert-header,
.alert-header.info {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #02baf2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.alert-header.success {
  background-color: #00cc1b;
}

.alert-header.danger {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.alert-header.warning {
  background-color: #f7931e;
}

.alert-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.alert-footer,
.alert-footer.info {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  background-color: #02baf2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.alert-footer.success {
  background-color: #00cc1b;
}

.alert-footer.danger {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.alert-footer.warning {
  background-color: #f7931e;
}

.alert-close,
.alert-close.info {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #02baf2;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #666;
}

.alert-close.success {
  color: #00cc1b;
}

.alert-close.danger {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.alert-close.warning {
  color: #f7931e;
}

.alert-close:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.alert-close:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.displayBox {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #130e5a;
}

.header h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

div.icon-box-top {
  margin: 50px 0px 25px 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

div.icon-box {
  margin: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

p.icon-text,
p.menuText {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: left;
}

p.menuText {
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.textPopup {
  /*When attaching popups to text menus, style text menu separately*/
  display: block;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #130e5a;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 75px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

p.textPopup.pressed {
  color: #02baf2 !important;
}

div#myPopUp,
div#myPopUp2,
div#myPopUp3,
div#myPopUp4 {
  margin-left: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
}

i.swIcon {
  font-size: 208px !important;
  margin: 10px;
}
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="icon-box-top">
  <div id="defaultTest" style="margin-left: 75px">
    <i class="fa fa-cog leftBorder rightBorder"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an example I'm working from which works fine.  When I duplicate that code in my app, the icon looks too small and off center.

Here is how it is supposed to look, per example:
[image]

Here is how it looks when I enter the same code:
[image]

It is smaller and the cog is off center.

Here is the example's html:

```
    <div class="icon-box-top">
        <div id="defaultTest" style="margin-left: 75px">
            <i class="fa fa-cog leftBorder rightBorder"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div class="icon-box-top">
        <div id="defaultTest" style="margin-left: 75px">
            <i class="fa fa-cog leftBorder rightBorder"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the example's dependencies:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Popup-plugin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/Example.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- necessary for the "draggable" ui  -->
<script src="scripts/Popup-plugin.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/Example.js"></script>
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Popup-plugin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Example.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- necessary for the "draggable" ui  -->
<script src="js/Popup-plugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/Example.js"></script>
```

The only difference that I can see is he stores his javascript in scripts folder and mine is in js folder. And he stores his css in styles folder whereas mine is in css folder.

The javascript is the same too:

```
$('#defaultTest').popup();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I add a code snippet that produces the correct output for the example.  But you have to click the link "show code snippet" and then scroll to the bottom to actually run it.  I must have done something wrong.

Comment: you must be setting some style that affects the div.icon-box-top. Explore the style differences using dev console in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.  There was a bootstrap css library that was interfering with the Popup-plugin css.  But now my bootstrap tabs don't work and I'll have to spend additional time looking at different versions of it, or replacing the tabs with something else.  I figured there was a css conflict somewhere but it took me all day to find it.  This has happened to me before and it is a painful and time-consuming process to isolate the problem and fix it.  If anyone has suggestions of tools or techniques for speeding up this process, please leave comments below for everyone reading this to benefit.